# Combining multiple columns in 1 resultset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE sales
    (`id` int, `date` date, `amount` int(4))
;

insert into sales values (1, '2012-09-01', 200),
                         (2, '2012-09-01', 300),
                         (3, '2012-09-02', 400),
                         (4, '2012-09-02', 500),
                         (5, '2012-09-02', 600)
```

I wish to retrieve a row showing the sales for today, and the sales for yesterday

like

```
Date             Today Total sales   Yesterday Sales
2012-09-02       1500                500
```

Tried using something like

```
SELECT id, date, sum(amount) FROM sales
GROUP BY date;
```

But it returns the sales day wise. I understand that can be done programmatically, but is there a better way to directly retrieve it from the DB?

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1eff/3)

Comment: Try using a 'having' clause. As I don't use mysql, I can't quickly write up a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, date(now()) as `date`, 
      SUM(IF(date(`date`) = date(now()), `amount`, 0)) as TodayTotalSales,
      SUM(IF(date(`date`) < date(now()), `amount`, 0)) as OtherDaySales
FROM sales;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ef6a/18

Comment: Won't this provide the sum of all previous days, rather than just yesterday? Otherwise, good answer. Much more efficient than mine, once there are lots of records, I expect.

Comment: It could be written as now()-1 day

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that because `Id` is different for each record. You have two option now:

1. Don't retrieve Id and write query like:

   ```
   SELECT date, sum(amount) FROM sales
   GROUP BY date;
   ```
2. Use a join with subquery

   ```
   SELECT a.ID, a.date, b.amount
   FROM sales a, (SELECT date, sum(amount) amount FROM sales
                  GROUP BY date) b
   WHERE a.date = b.date;
   ```

   **Please Note:** In option 2, second and third columns will be repeating with same value for each id within a day.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, sum(amount), yestersales 
FROM sales AS s1, 
    (SELECT sum(amount) as yestersales, ADDDATE(date, 1) AS yesterdate 
        FROM sales GROUP BY date) AS s2
WHERE s1.date = s2.yesterdate
GROUP BY date;
```

Will do what you want, but it's not really very efficient, I don't think. I would personally do it in code.

Selecting the ID doesn't really make much sense here since you're grouping by date.